# Silverlight 4 SDK

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have to modify a very legacy Silverlight 4 application in VS2012.
But I cannot found where can I download SL4 SDK.
Does somebody know where could I find it?
Unfortunately it is not an option to upgraded it to SL5.
Br,
Jozsef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the WayBack Machine has it.
http://web.archive.org/web/20120503175703/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18149

I have confirmed that the Tools download has the SDK in it.

From the Microsoft search results:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=silverlight&first=21
You take the bad URL:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18149
To the way back machine, it will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

- The accepted answer actually provides a link to Silverlight 4 tools for VS2010 but I needed Silverlight 4 SDK
- I found this link https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/B/B9BDD218-6974-4816-A309-0FC85A105521/sdk/silverlight_sdk.exe, it's not valid anymore but using Wayback Machine I was able to get that file. Here is the link https://web.archive.org/web/20151018151935/https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/B/B9BDD218-6974-4816-A309-0FC85A105521/sdk/silverlight_sdk.exe